# Midori and Java plugin

Tags: midori

How can you get java plugin to work in midorι? I have tried to use some web apps that require java and they don't work because it seems that midori can't find the proper java plugin like Firefox does.
Any help appreciated bercause I would like to use mainly midori, since it is very light and fast.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing java and enabling java plug-in

Instructions:

- Install jdk from [here](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/)
- Enable plugin.

  Go to *preferences* --> extensions

  [image: Imgur]

*Note*: You can verify at: https://minecraft.net/

If java plugin not enabled: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbBkf.jpg)

After enabling : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiTSB.jpg)